# OAuth 2.0 Auth code grant - Is there anyway to Authenticate user when requesting for Auth Code

Tags: oauth-2.0

Whats the best way to programmatically authenticate user using OAuth 2.0 Authentication Code Grant ?

Wondering if there is a way to combine step A and B as stated on the spec - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1, i.e pass user ID and password as part of authorize call ? Something like,
/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3&state=xyz
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb&user_id=john.doe@mail&password=xxxx

I believe one way is to submit() the form returned by the Authorization server with user id and password. Taking this route would create a dependency on the form and any changes to it given it is not a public API.

Answer (score 2):

The Authorization Code grant is designed to be used with a full browser i.e. should not be used to authenticate the user programmatically. In fact using it programmatically would defeat the purpose of OAuth 2.0 to not divulge the user's credentials to the Client.

Grants like Client Credentials and Resource Owner Password Credentials have been designed to be used with non-browser Clients.

Alternatively you could create an access_token and refresh_token for your Client in a browser using the Authorization Code grant, then pass the tokens to your non-browser Client so that it can use the refresh_token on its own to obtain a new access token when the old one expires.